# realloc two dimensional struct array

Tags: c, struct, realloc

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct a // linked list node
{
    char* st;
    struct a* pr;
    struct a* nx;
};

struct a* Init(char* w);
struct a* insert(struct a* old, char* w);

int main(void)
{
    struct a** A;
    A = (struct a**)malloc(sizeof(struct a*));
    A[0] = Init("HELLO");
    A[0] = insert(A[0], "WORLD");

    // I think the problem is here.
    A = (struct a**)realloc(A, 2*sizeof(struct a*));
    A[1] = Init("ELLO");
    A[1] = insert(A[1], "ORLD");

    free(A); 

    return 0;
}

struct a* Init(char* w)
{
    struct a* body = (struct a*)malloc(sizeof(struct a));
    struct a* tail = (struct a*)malloc(sizeof(struct a));

    body -> pr = NULL;
    body -> nx = tail;
    body -> st = w;

    tail -> pr = body;
    tail -> nx = NULL;
    tail -> st = NULL;

    return tail;
}

struct a* insert(struct a* old, char* w)
{
    struct a* tail = (struct a*)malloc(sizeof(struct a*));

    old -> nx = tail;
    old -> st = w;
    tail -> pr = old;
    tail -> nx = NULL;
    tail -> st = NULL;

    return tail;
}
```

(I abridged my code)
I constructed two dimensional structure array, but this code keeps giving me an error, segmentation fault.

I think the problem is here.

```
A = (struct a**)realloc(A, 2*sizeof(struct a*));
```

But I have no idea why it is wrong.
Is there any idea?

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Compile error: `prog.c: In function 'Init':
prog.c:43:10: error: 'struct a' has no member named 'wr'
     tail -> wr = NULL;`

Comment: @ MikeCAT sorry. since I revised my original code, I mistyped. I corrected

Comment: @BLUEPIXY maybe this line: A = (struct a**)realloc(A, 2*sizeof(struct a*));

Comment: "maybe"? Did you use a debugger?

Comment: Your `sizeof(struct a*)` differs from sizeof(struct a) in the two functions and you have 4 mallocs and one realloc and one `free`.

Answer (score 1):

In `insert()` function, you allocated room for only one pointer by this line

```
struct a* tail = (struct a*)malloc(sizeof(struct a*));
```

On the other hand, `struct a` has three pointers, so its size will be larger than size of one pointer in typical environment.

Therefore, some out-of-range access will happen. Try allocating `sizeof(struct a)` as you did in `Init()` function.